# placing the figures same as the attached in a two column paper format

Tags: floats, subfloats, subfig, sidewaysfigure

I'd like to place my figures (png files) same as the attached image (picture2.jpg). would you please help me how to correct my LATEX code to produce that?
Thanks in advance

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{VED5.png}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{VED16.png}}
    \\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{HED5.png}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{HED16.png}}
        \\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{RE5.png}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{RE16.png}}
    \caption{The} \label{results}
 \end{figure*}
```

[image: picture2.jpg]
[image: RE16.png]
[image: RE5.png]
[image: HED16.png]
[image: HED5.png]
[image: VED16.png]
[image: VED5.png]

Comment: Welcome. Do you want captions for each subfigures?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the figures aligned in one column, you just have to change your code slightly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \\
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \\ 
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \\
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \\
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \\
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \caption{The} \label{results}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]